# Correct usage of Hashmaps for synonyms

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to store synonyms of a given word into a `HashMap`. I then take the user input and check to see if it is a word or its synonym. For example, suppose the main word is "bank" and its synonmyns are "safe","tresury" and "credit union". If the user enters "bank", I want to output the word "bank". If the user enters " safe", I still want to output the word "bank" because "safe" is a synonym of "bank".

Here is my Synonymn method

```
public static void populateSynonymMap() {
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();

    String word = "bank";
    String synonymn[] = { "safe", "treasury", "credit union" };

    synonymMap.put(word, synonymn);

}
```

and here is my main method

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException, IOException {
    /* Initialization */
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    HashMap<String, String[]> synonymMap = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    synonmynMap = populateSynonymMap(); //populate the map

    boolean found = false;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;

    System.out.println("Welcome To Artifical Intelligence DataBase ");
    System.out.println("What would you like to know?");

    System.out.print("> ");
    input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your synonymMap should be organised other way arround, the key are the "synonyms" and the value is their common output.

So in your example:

```
String word = "bank";
String synonymn[] = { "safe", "treasury", "credit union" };

for (String syn : synonymn)
    synonymMap.put(syn, word);
```

Then when user enters a word you check if it exists in the synonymMap and if so you return its value:

```
String syn = synonynMap.get(input);
if (syn != null) return syn;
else return input;
```

Comment: You could not should. The simple if statement deals with it as in the code above and it allows to distinguis between the synonyms and original words if such a feature is needed.

Comment: You did not make it very clear in your answer. Don't really know where you would use the second snippet.

Answer (score 0):

you can add every word of your synonym[] as key to your map too. of course with an array of synonyms containing the word and all other synonyms. i know there have to be better approaches, but thats the easiest way i can think of at the moment